# Make an if statement shorter

Tags: php, if-statement

Hay all, I have an `if` statement. How could I make this as short as possible?

```
 if ( $a < 0 ){
   if( $a > -2 ){
    echo "standard";
   }elseif( $a <= -2 && $a > -4 ){
    echo "thin";
   }elseif( $a <= -4 ){
    echo "super thin";
   }

 }else{
  if( $a < 2 ){
    echo "standard";
  }
  if( $a > 2.01 && $a <= 4){
    echo "thin";
  }
  if( $a > 4.01 && $a <= 8.00){
    echo "super thin";
  }
}
```

EDIT: basically `$a` will be any number (positive or negative) and we match it like this.

If the value is

- +0.00 to +/- 2.00 – Standard
- +/- 2.25 to +/- 4.00 – Thin
- +/- 4.25 to +/- 8.00 – Super Thin

Extra marks for anyone who knows what this might be used for :)

Comment: Caveat: what happens for "$a = 2.005" ? Nothing?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description. Your code will give "super thin" to -100.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can shorten it by using the absolute value:

```
$b = abs($a);
if ($b <= 2) {
    echo "standard";
} else if ($b <= 4) {
    echo "thin";
} else if ($b <= 8) {
    echo "super thin";
}
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP wants. Notice, however, that the original code produces no output for values > 8.

Comment: This is wrong. First statement catches every value that is bigger than 2, so the others won't execute. Also, what number is $b <= 2 && $b > 4 (less than two and bigger than four)?

Comment: And also not for values between 2 and 2.01 or between 4 and 4.01 - but I doubt that's actually intended behaviour.

Comment: So, wait, you essentially saw reiner's answer, realized that his idea of not including the $b >= 2 in the else if was good, and swiped it for your own answer?

Comment: Even after your edit your code is wrong, as it doesn't give "super thin" for -100.

Comment: I dont think the value will ever be more than (+/-) 20.

Comment: Yeah, I read your edit. Your code isn't doing what you want :)

Comment: @R. Bemrose: The different conditions for negative and positive numbers were a little bit confusing. I needed some time to figure it out what boundaries he meant.

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

```
 $a = abs($a);
 if($a<=2) echo "standard";
 elseif($a<=4) echo "thin";
 elseif($a<=8) echo "super thin";
```

Comment: @n1313:  The question doesn't give what anything less than -8 or greater than 8 should be.  If it did, then an else condition could be added to it.

Answer (score 4):

This is about as simple as it gets:

```
<?php
$b = abs($a);
$ranges = array(
  'standard' => 2,
  'thin' => 4,
  'super thin' => 8
);
foreach($ranges as $range=>$max) {
    $size = $range;
    if($b > $max) continue;
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what enamors novices about elseif, since it's hardly ever the best solution. Voting this up. 

My answer is similar, and also includes custom ranges and accounts for values less than -8.

Comment: @ringmaster: If you convert to absolute value, this will always work, regardless of sign and it will work for values more than the absolute value of +/-8. For instance, if the value is `-9` (i.e. `9`... because of `abs()`), `$size` would be set to `standard`, fail, then `"thin"`, fail again, then `"super thin"`, and would fail once more... but then the loop would be over and `$size` would still be `"super thin"`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can keep the actual ranges, allow the range ends to be different (rather than just the absolute values), and allow easy inclusion of additional ranges:

```
$ranges = array(
  'standard' => array(-2, 2),
  'thin' => array(-4, 4),
  'super thin' => array(null,8),
);
foreach($ranges as $key => $range) {
  if((is_null($range[0]) || $a => $range[0]) && (is_null($range[1]) || $a <= $range[1])) {
    echo $key;
    break;
  }
}
```

The first matching range in the list is the one that qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $a < 0 )
{
    if( $a > -2 ) echo "standard";
    elseif($a > -4) echo "thin";
    else echo  "super thin";
}
else
{
  if( $a < 2 ) echo "standard";
  elseif( $a > 2.01 && $a <= 4) echo "thin";
  elseif( $a > 4.01 && $a <= 8.00) echo "super thin";
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Its always better to use `switch` rather than `else if`! It makes the code cleaner and extensible.

```
switch($a) {
    case (-2 < $a):
    case ($a < 2):
        $r = 'Standard';
    break;

    case ( 2.25 > $a):
    case (-2.25 < $a):
    case ($a <  4):
    case ($a > -4):
        $r = 'Thin';
    break;


    case ( 4.25 > $a):
    case (-4.25 < $a):
    case ($a <  8):
    case ($a > -8):
        $r = 'Super Thin';
    break;

    default:
        $r = 'Out of range';
} 

echo $r;
```

---

> The case expression may be any
> expression that evaluates to a simple
> type, that is, integer or
> floating-point numbers and strings.
> Arrays or objects cannot be used here
> unless they are dereferenced to a
> simple type.

Taken from the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Except you can't use switch for ranges.

Comment: `$x < $y < $z` isn't a valid expression in php.